# I am getting "ln: /usr/local/bin/<Cask>: Permission denied" when trying to install some casks

Tags: macos, permissions, sudo, homebrew, non-admin

I have installed Homebrew and Cask to my machine, and it has worked for some things. But I sometimes get an error saying

```
==> ln: /usr/local/bin/<Cask name>: Permission denied
Error: Command failed to execute!
```

I know why this is caused, and how to fix it *using `sudo`*, but is there a way to do it even temporally *without `sudo`*?

P.S.
How it is done with `sudo`:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to run the command itself as the super user:

```
sudo brew install FORMULA
```

you can temporarily grant yourself super user priveleges by entering:

```
su USERNAME
```

then you can just simply enter:

```
brew install FORMULA
```

Either way, you'll have to enter your password, but with the second method, you'll only have to enter it once, as you will remain a super user for the remainder of the terminal session.